# Compiling SASS and SUSY with GULP

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, susy-sass

I am trying to get gulp to compile my `sass` and use the `susy` grid/framework.

I'm having troubles finding any information about this online.

I have included:

```
"gulp-ruby-sass": "^0.7.1",
```

into my `package.json` and installed everything.

My gulp `sass` gulp task likes like so:

```
gulp.task('sass', ['images'], function () {
  return gulp.src('src/sass/*.{sass, scss}')
    .pipe(sass({
      bundleExec: true,
      sourcemap: true,
      sourcemapPath: '../sass'
    }))
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

So I can't for the life of me work out how to include `susy` so it complies using `gulp`, I haven't looked and can't seem to find anything relating to this online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gulp-compass`, you only need to have compass installed in your system and install `gulp-compass` package through npm, here is a sample code:

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/*.scss')
  .pipe(compass({
    // Gulp-compass options and paths
    css: 'app/assets/css',
    sass: 'app/assets/sass',
    require: ['susy']
  }))
  .on('error', handleErrors)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/temp'));
});
```

More info about this package [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compass)

Comment: Bingo good sir. I however wanted to include it without compass so I used the `gulp-sass` module. But thats not important. The require was the key.

Comment: It seems that gulp-compass is rejected by gulp community !

Answer (score 1):

To have more details from Jamie's answer, here is what you can do to use susy without compass..

1. download .zip package of susy from github. extract package into
   node_modules directory.
2. In my case I put it in susy-master folder.
3. In gulpfile.js, you could have some thing like this to include susy package. Note that the important is to put correct includePath value to be the same path of the susy-master folder..

   ```
   gulp.task('sass', function(){
     gulp.src('public/sass/styles.scss')
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(sass({
           outputStyle: 'compressed',
           includePaths: ['node_modules/susy-master/sass']
       }).on('error', sass.logError))

       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
   });
   ```
4. Import susy in styles.scss

   ```
   @import "susy";
   ```