# Dealing with Gulp, Bundler, Ruby and Susy

Tags: sass, gulp, bundler, susy

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838414/compiling-sass-and-susy-with-gulp) it's possible to compile susy install from Ruby with Gulp.
But is it possible to use gulp-sass instead of gulp-compass or gulp-ruby-sass because of performance and deprecation ?
Actually I use this in my gulpfile.js:

**gulpfile**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include plugins
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// Variables de chemins
var source = './sass/**/*.scss'; // dossier de travail
var destination = './css/'; // dossier à livrer   

gulp.task('sasscompil', function () {
  return gulp.src(source)
  .pipe(plugins.sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      includePaths: ['/home/webmaster/vendor/bundle/gems/susy-2.2.2/sass']
  }).on('error', sasscompil.logError))
  .pipe(plugins.csscomb())
  .pipe(plugins.cssbeautify({indent: '  '}))
  .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + ''));
});
```

But the error log doesn't work because sasscompil isn't define.
Then I need to give the path for all ex-compass includes like susy, sassy-button,etc..
is it possible to give a global path for gems ?
other thing, do I install gulp plugins despite of using gulp-load-plugins ? because gulp doesn't find plugins if I don't do that.

Thanks

Comment: try changing `sasscompil` to `plugins.sass.logError` - can leave an answer below. (we're passing the error back to `node-sass` which is used by `gulp-sass` to output the error) [ref](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#options)

Comment: did the above work?

Comment: yes ,changing to ``plugins.sass.logError`` give me ``Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    sass/application.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: sassy-buttons.
       Parent style sheet: /var/www/drupal-6/sites/all/themes/starter-susy2-nc-d6/sass/application.scss
        on line 33 of sass/application.scss
``

Comment: now, we need to look after others points : gems path and gulp plugins

Comment: you have an error with importing `/var/www/drupal-6/sites/all/themes/starter-susy2-nc-d6/sass/‌​application.scss` to `sass/application.scss`

I'm going to submit the answer as it solved the issue/question
the import error is related to the scss file and not the `gulp-task`

Comment: I don't think so, the error is from I don't actually give the path to the concerned gems like sassy-buttons, it works for susy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142584/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-webmaster-pf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `sasscompil.logError` to `plugins.sass.logError`

such that

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('sasscompil', function () {
  return gulp.src(source)
  .pipe(plugins.sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      includePaths: ['/home/webmaster/vendor/bundle/gems/susy-2.2.2/sass']
  }).on('error', plugins.sass.logError))
...
});
```

**gulp-sass doc:**

> Pass in options just like you would for node-sass; they will be passed along just as if you were using node-sass. Except for the data option which is used by gulp-sass internally. Using the file option is also unsupported and results in undefined behaviour that may change without notice.

**example**

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```